# Reflection for plugins

Tags: java, reflection

In C I could write a plugin by having a shared library implement the following interface:

```
extern "C" int initialize(SomeArgument * state);
extern "C" int shutdown(SomeArgument * state);
```

Obviously this is a *very* high level interface, but I think it gets the point across.  I've heard that a good use of reflection is to write plugins, but why would that be superior to what I have here?  Using an interface like this gives the following advantages:

- faster (reflection isn't fast, both looking up methods and calling indirectly)
- memory (reflection has memory overhead)
- straight-forward (entry/exit points for the plugin are intuitively obvious)

Am I just missing something?

Comment: In your example SomeArgument is still some agreed upon item that both libraries can compile against.  It is useful to be able to write a plugin that is not constrained to have to compile against what it takes as an argument, and can handle things that obey a specification not enforcable with simply an interface.  (e.g.,  classes annotated with the JPA @Entity.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no clear reason why reflection should be used over an interface, and many reasons to use interfaces over reflection. I guess it is clear.

All of you that supplied answers, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage I can think of is that you can use a properties file which contains `plugins` to be loaded dynamically at runtime (via reflection).

Or you could scan a specific directory for plugins and (try) loading / instantiating them automagically via reflection.

That does not mean these plugins should not implement a specific interface, of course.

Comment: Although not cross-platform in C, I could still get the list of files in some directory and attempt to load them.  `dlopen` will return a `NULL` if it could not load a library (as will `dlsym` if `initialize` is not found).  Couldn't I just have a configuration file that lists which plugins to load automagically and replace the need for the properties file?

Comment: One difference could be that you wouldn't be able to dynamically parse (validate) the function signature at runtime (iirc). But you could create a similar mechanism in C I guess. In Java it would be hard (without reflection).

Answer (score 0):

Consider this useful plugin interface:

```
public interface EntityAuditor {

    <T> void auditEntity(Class<T> clazz, T entity);

}
```

With the constraint that T must be a legally annotated JPA @Entity or a runtime exception is thrown.  It's not really practical to create some kind of interface that must be obyeed by every entity in the system that you want your plugin to audit.  You could have some kind of 'auditable entity' interface that returns the info the plugin needs, but now there's implementation and coupling inside the entities about how and what gets audited!  The whole point of the plugin is to abstract that out and be able to change how/what gets audited *without* making changes to the entities.

Answer (score 0):

One opinion is that a plugin works well integrated onto an IDE like Eclipse or Visual Studio .NET unlike the "C" interfaces you listed. Within the IDE for example, the tool can list all the public/exposed functions including parameters. These days with OO programming, the interfaces are more complicated. If the plugin works well with the IDE, then the interface is much more clearly understood.

Some plugins are GUI based and expose events/listeners, and that is more complicated than a "C" interface.
Is all that making sense?

Answer (score 0):

1. Reflection can be used to read class static variables and invoke class static methods.  Reading class static variables can be used to get information about the plugin (like its version number) without having to first create an instance.  Invoking a class static method can be used to implement the plugin as a singleton.
2. If the plugin isn't to be a singleton, reflection can be used to call a constructor which accepts arguments, while without reflection you can only call the no-argument constructor.